# Wordpress Custom Post Type Posts Not Showing Up in Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this theme called IronBand.

It has a few custom post types, and one of them is called "Gig."

I created some custom posts under that Custom Post Type.

Then I wanted to changed the name of the Custom Post Type to "Show," so I fiddled with some php files.

Then it seemed like it was too complicated to change everything accordingly, so I replaced the php files I fiddled with to the original php files.

But now in the admin panel of "Gig," it says "No Gigs Found" Even if above the post list it says there are 17 published posts.

How could I make the published posts show up again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old slug will still be in the database, and that is what WP uses to find the custom post types. Have a look at the URL in admin. It would currently be:

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=show
```

As the old posts are still associated with the post type "gig", they will not be found in the Admin panel.

This happened to me recently, and I think I just went and changed the relevant values/slugs manually in the DB.

Comment: How I fixed it at the end was changing the dates of the posts in the DB to today's date. Not sure how that solved the problem exactly.